# Setting log factory logic from outside settings.py

Tags: python-3.x, django, logging, python-logging, django-logging

I have a Django application where I want to update the standard logging to structured JSON format.  I can get this working fine by adding my logging config and some business logic into `settings.py`, but I want to keep the business logic separate.

Is there any Django built-in file (akin to the `settings.py`) that allows you to add some logic that Django will pick up, or can I load a file with this additional logic from `settings.py`?

Here is what I have:

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'structured': {
            'format':'%(json_structured)s',
            'datefmt': "%H:%M:%S"
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        ...
    },
    'loggers': {
        ...
    }
}

# Below is what I want to move from settings.py
class JsonDateTimeEncoder(JsonStringFallbackEncoder):
  def default(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime):
      return obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
    else:
      return super().default(obj)

std_record_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

def structured_log_record_factory(*args, **kwargs) -> logging.LogRecord:
  record = std_record_factory(*args, **kwargs)
  
  record.json_structured = json.dumps(
    {
      'level': record.levelname,
      ...
    },
    cls=JsonDateTimeEncoder,
  )
  return record

logging.setLogRecordFactory(structured_log_record_factory)
```

I know I can load the `LOGGING` config from file, but not sure how best to achieve this with the additional logic.